# Scala Slick User defined key generation sequence

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

With JPA we are populating primary key for a table.
Sample code:

```
@Id
@Column(name=“R_ID” , nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator=“sequence_name”)
Public long id;
```

How can we use the same sequence Using Slick ?